# How do I create maven package of github

Tags: android, maven, github, repository, repo

I want to create a package of my android dependency - https://github.com/dev-aniketj

What kind of steps I have to perform to create my own package??

I already research on it and my project is based on android, so have make maven package, but don't how to create it.

Please Help me !!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is not here to replace search engines, documentation, or tutorials. Have you put "create maven package" into your favourite search engine? What did you find? What have you tried?

Comment: @Chris i already tried many times

Comment: pls try this : https://gist.github.com/fernandezpablo85/03cf8b0cd2e7d8527063